# Sql table Syntax error

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have created a lot of sql databases in Android in past. I don't know what i am doing wrong but i get this error.

> 08-02 09:22:11.335: E/AndroidRuntime(8795): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "from": syntax error (code 1):

while compiling:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friendsdatabase (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    from TEXT NOT NULL,
    isImage TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    fromMe TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    isLocation TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    isImageSticker TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
    isVideo TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    status TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sending'
);
```

My Android sql Query is:

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " ("
                + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + KEY_From
                + " TEXT NOT NULL,isImage TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',fromMe TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',isLocation TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',isImageSticker TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',isVideo TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',status TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sending');");
```

I have tried changing many things but i get error at same place.

Comment: is from a reserved word?

Comment: If your problem is with `SQLite` why did you tagged `MySQL`?

Comment: No i have used from in other tables and it works well

Comment: change 'from' and test, i think error is because of the 'from' reserved word

Comment: Or put `[from]` in square brackets and test.

Comment: http://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html shows that `FROM` is a keyword and "may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object."  It is _wrong_ in SQLite, whether or not you used it in the past. :)

Comment: Yes well that solved it, Also learned something new.Kritner can you post as answer so i will accept as you pointed it out first.

Comment: i think you hav assigned like this KEY_From="from",just change from word.its a reserved keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the money from the error message, it looks like the statement constructed contains `...from TEXT NOT NULL...`, which is definitely invalid SQL.  Something fishy about the `KEY_From` name, in the Android context?